# GNU CLISP: finding the modification time of a file

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I'm coding for GNU CLISP:

```
GNU CLISP 2.48 (2009-07-28)
```

I guess I have two questions:

1. How do I find when a file was last modified, using CLISP's POSIX package?
2. Where could I have looked to find this answer for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Posix:file-stat` returns a structure with a slot `mtime`.
- Search for "clisp posix file date" (I used duckduckgo): http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/syscalls.html